# Masking a number by showing last "x" digits with 1 mask character in front

Tags: vb.net, masking

Im attempting to get this function to return a masked number.  Say i have number 123456789.  Im trying to get it to return *6789 if i give in an unmasked value of 4, or *789 if i give it an unmasked value of 3.  Currently it is showing the number of digits in the number, which is what im trying to hide.  I have been toying around with this but i cant quite get it to do what I want.

```
Public Function GetMaskedNumber(ByVal sNumber As String, ByVal iUnmaskedLength As Integer, ByVal sMaskChar As String) As String
    sMaskChar = Trim(sMaskChar)
    If iUnmaskedLength > 0 AndAlso Len(sMaskChar) > 0 Then
        GetMaskedNumber = New String(sMaskChar(0), iUnmaskedLength)
        If iUnmaskedLength < Len(sNumber) Then
            Mid(GetMaskedNumber, (Len(sNumber) - iUnmaskedLength), iUnmaskedLength + 1) = Right(sNumber, iUnmaskedLength)
        Else
            GetMaskedNumber = sNumber
        End If
    Else
        GetMaskedNumber = sNumber
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the number you want to mask as an Integer (say iNumber) rather than a string, you could use

```
"*" & CStr(iNumber mod (10 ^ iUnmaskedLength))
```

(Note that in vb.net `^` is exponentation.)

If you don't and need to work with sNumber then use

```
"*" & Right(sNumber, iUnmaskedLength)
```

`Right()` allows `iUnmaskedLength` to be larger than the length of the string; in such cases it returns the input string.

Comment: Wow incredibly simple. I was overcomplicating it. Right() will work for this perfectly fine.

Comment: RIGHT() is holdover from VB6.

Answer (score 0):

With some error checking.

test code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'test
    Dim i As Long = Long.MaxValue
    Dim s As String = GetMaskedNumber(i, 12)
    s = GetMaskedNumber(i, 20)
End Sub
```

the function

```
Public Function GetMaskedNumber(ByVal theNum As Long, _
                                ByVal UnmaskedLength As Integer, _
                                Optional MaskChar As String = "*") As String
    Dim retval As String = theNum.ToString
    If retval.Length > UnmaskedLength Then
        retval = String.Format("{0}{1}", MaskChar, retval.Substring(retval.Length - UnmaskedLength))
    Else
        'ERROR???
        Stop
    End If
    Return retval
End Function
```